# What does this famous quote mean?

Tags: quotations

In *Serenity (2005)*, Kaylee says to Malcolm, who deserted Simon and River:

> Kaylee: Going on a year now, I ain't had nothing twixt my nethers
> weren't run on batteries.

What does this famous quote mean?

Comment: It means what it says.  What is the problem understanding this?  The grammar is casual and in the style of the show, and so is the vocabulary.

Comment: And you're probably aware of this, but the dialogue of *Firefly* (and *Serenity*) is not necessarily standard English, but is an imaginary dialect of speculative fiction, peppered with invented colloquialisms and intentional archaisms. In other words, "'twixt" or substituting "weren't" for "wasn't" isn't modern standard usage.

Comment: Also notable is the omission of "that" from "that wasn't run on batteries".

Comment: This is not a famous quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Nethers" refers to your sex organs. "Twixt" means "in between" and "weren't run on batteries" refers to a battery powered sex toy. So the speaker is saying they haven't had sex in a year.